Blazor CSS isolation does not work, but when I save the file, it works
I have this code:
razor and razor.css file tree
Isolation.razor:
@page "/css/isolation"

<h3>Isolation</h3>
<h1>TEST</h1>

Isolation.razor.css:
h1 {
    color: tomato;
}

It seems like it does not work at first in debug mode:
CSS isolation does not work
but when I save the Isolation.razor.css file:
CSS isolation does work
I created a new Blazor project and compared it to mine, but I don't know what the problem is. It worked fine for the new project.
And I checked {ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css
@import '_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.bundle.scp.css';
@import '_content/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.bundle.scp.css';

/* _content/{ASSEMBLY NAME}/Components/Pages/Css/Isolation.razor.rz.scp.css */
h1[b-n08r7a8kqo] {
    color: tomato;
}

I think it looks like it was created correctly.

I solved this by moving the existing content into a new project. It was a small project, so it made sense, but I'm still frustrated because I don't know what's causing the problem.

Are you sure it works differently in your new project? I.e. make a change, no save, start the app.

Yes I am. But then I noticed something strange. The identifier in the css file generated by blazor ({ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css) was different from the identifier seen in the developer tools on the web page. This was probably the problem, but the frustrating thing is that I don't know what caused it. Maybe it's because I've tried to style dynamically fetched MarkupString in the past and didn't revert some settings properly.

have you tried hard refreshing the browser page to load the changes? there might be a possibility that the files are getting cached. You mentioned working with dynamically fetched MarkupString. If there were any special handling done to support this, make sure that these changes aren't affecting the CSS isolation mechanism. Have you checked the console if is there any error or not?  Your issue seems to be related some configuration in your old project.
